# Semantic Media Wiki (SMW) - Is it possible to nest property / value definitions?

Tags: properties, nested, glossary, semantic-mediawiki

I'm using Semantic Media Wiki in conjunction with the Lingo Extension and the Semantic Glossary Extension to build a glossary. Often definitions of a term include links to other terms. For example: Computer - A calculating machine which uses a -CPU- to execute calculations. The definition includes a link to the term 'CPU'.

Now I wonder: Is it possible to nest a link to a wiki page inside a property / value definition?

I tried the following without success:

```
A [[Glossary-term::Computer]] is a 
[[Glossary-Definition::calculating machine 
which uses a [[CPU]] to execute calculations.]]
```

Does anybody know how to reach this structure?

Thanks for your ideas an suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution through the [SMW mailing list](http://sourceforge.net/p/semediawiki/mailman/message/22626387/) citing [SMW Configuration Page](http://semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aConfiguration#Installation_settings) :

You can use

```
A [[Glossary-term::Computer]] is a 
[[Glossary-Definition::calculating machine 
which uses a [[CPU]] to execute calculations.]]
```

but you have to add the following to your LocalSettings.php in the MediaWiki root:

```
$smwgLinksInValues=true;
```